# What is the better way to build arm64 binaries?

Tags: gcc, build, arm64

I have a number C/C++ project which must be compiled for arm64 (aarch64) Linux platform, then packet into both RPM and DEB packages, then published. Creating and publishing Linux software for arm64.
How to build aarch64 binaries using amd64 Linux host system?
I have the following linux

```
katya7@katya7-comp:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="KDE neon"
VERSION="5.25"
ID=neon
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="KDE neon User - 5.25"
VARIANT="User Edition"
VARIANT_ID=user
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://neon.kde.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://neon.kde.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kde.org/"
LOGO=start-here-kde-neon
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cross compiling? There is a nice blog post on how to do cross compiling for aarch64 on a build platform with a different architecture. https://jensd.be/1126/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-or-aarch64-on-debian-or-ubuntu